# how can write a Subqueries with a autocolumn in table1 depends on column in table2

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE voiture
    (
        matricule INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      , modele VARCHAR(89)
      , prixlocation FLOAT
      , id_marque INT
    );

CREATE TABLE [location]
    (
        idloc INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      , nopermis VARCHAR(543)
      , matricule INT
      , datelocation DATETIME
      , daterotour DATETIME
      , dureelocation INT
      , montanttotal FLOAT
    );
```

---

```
alter table location 
 add    montanttotal 
 as dureelocation*(select prixlocation 
                   from voiture 
                   where matricule=location.matricule ) ;
```

Comment: the column named" montanttotal " is dropped  from table location

Comment: Why don't you use a Trigger on Insert and Update?

Comment: `"create trigger t1 on location after  insert 
as
begin 
declare @id int ;
declare @dayss int ;
set @id=(select prixlocation from voiture where  matricule =(  select matricule from inserted) );
set @dayss=(select dureelocation from inserted) ;
update location set montanttotal=@id*@dayss;
en`

Comment: i already use it but i want know why I can't do it with a simple query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.  After the insert to 'location' table, the inserted values are used to update the dureelocation column with the prixlocation from the 'voiture' table.

```
declare         @l  table(idloc                 int,
                          matricule             int,
                          dureelocation         int);                          

/* suppose a new row is inserted into locations, output the insert row(s) into temp table @l */
insert [Location](idloc, nopermis, matricule, datelocation, daterotour, dureelocation, montanttotal)
output inserted.idloc, inserted.matricule, inserted.dureelocation into @l
values (1, 'voila', 3, sysutcdatetime(), sysutcdatetime(), 2, 2.34);

/* after the row has been inserted, update to the prixlocation from 'voiture' table if necessary */
update l
set
  dureelocation=v.prixlocation
from [Location] lc
     join
     voiture v on lc.matricule=v.matricule
     join
     @l l on lc.idloc=l.idloc
where
  l.dureelocation<>v.prixlocation;
```